# What are the advantages of a Micro 4/3s camera compared to a DSLR?

Tags: micro-four-thirds

*After a quick search found none, I thought I'd follow up [IntuitionHQ's question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-a-micro-4-3s-camera-versus-a-dslr) with its opposite:*

When comparing cameras to buy, what are the **advantages** of Micro 4/3 cameras when compared with DSLRs?

There has to be some advantages - what are the important ones?