# Instructions for beginner

Tags: photography-basics, learning, amateur

I know this question would have been asked time and time again, I'm new to this blog so i haven't seen it yet. I'm a beginner with great interest to learn photography. I don't have any desire to pick this as my profession but for passion. Where do I start and what camera should i pick to kick start? Advice on question is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start learning photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-start-learning-photography) as well as [What should a photography beginner focus on?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/what-should-a-photography-beginner-focus-on) As for using this site, first start by using the search box at the top right of this site, and second by using the help information here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I know this could get downvoted but thanks for the information

Comment: *"I'm new to this blog"* Stack Exchange is not a blog. It is also not a discussion forum. It's a network of question and answers sites. I recommend taking the site [tour], which should only take a few minutes of your time but familiarize yourself with what Stack Exchange is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I start

**That depends on you.** Do you like to jump in with both feet and figure it out as you go, or do you like to proceed in an orderly fashion with the help of a good guide? Learning photography is like learning anything else -- there are many approaches you can take to knowledge. But, there are a LOT of people who are interested in photography, and so there are a LOT of resources available: books, blogs, tutorial sites, podcasts, YouTube, old-fashioned in-person classes, and so on. Find some interesting resource and start reading, listening, watching... The *way* you get started isn't nearly so important as just getting started *somehow*.

Eventually, you'll have gathered enough information to feel a little (or a lot) confused. Chances are, someone else has been confused along the same lines, and that's what this site, Photos.stackexchange.com, is for. Search the archive of questions and answers here and you'll probably find what you're looking for; if not, ask a question of your own.

> and what camera should i pick to kick start?

**The one you already have.** It seems like everybody has a phone or tablet with a camera these days, and if you are similarly equipped then you're ready to start [taking photographs](https://www.flickr.com/groups/iphone_users/pool/). Phone cameras have some big advantages: you always have it with you, there aren't many things you can screw up, and tools for editing the images you take are usually available on the same device. And you can of course still import the images into your computer and manipulate them just as you would with any other camera. A smartphone or an inexpensive point and shoot can get you started today with little or no investment in stuff, and you can start to figure out what kind of photos you want to take and what you'll need later on.